# Implement a vertical scrolling on a canvas

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, hammer.js

I try to implement a vertical scroller with touch pan event on a large background in a HTML5 canvas.
I use hammer JS to recognize pan gesture: http://hammerjs.github.io/

It works fine when I move y axis of the background but I want to reproduce the native scoll effect of IOS or Android scroll.

Is there any library or a simple JS to do that with the same smooth effect ?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Zynga has a pure logic component for scrolling/zooming. It is independent of any specific kind of rendering or event system:

http://zynga.github.com/scroller/

I believe you can easily use HammerJS for event handling and Scroller for scroll effect.